# Trouble with Restarting a Script While Keeping Track

Tags: linux, bash, restart

I have a script I'm working on in bash where after any input is given, after the input is processed, the whole thing is restarted using `exec bash "${BASH_SOURCE}"`, waiting to process the next input given by the user. This all works as intended, save for one catch. I need to run an `if` statement, but only so it runs when the script is first run. I've tried a multitude of solutions, but can't figure anything out. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in the end, but repeated exec's seem like it might be best handled another way.

That being said, here's a solution that works:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [ "$FIRST_RUN" = "" ] ; then
  FIRST_RUN=no
  export FIRST_RUN
  echo first run
fi

read ans
echo "answer: $ans"
exec bash "${BASH_SOURCE}"
```

Comment: Would probably choose `if [ -z "$FIRST_RUN" ]; then` as the first test, but rest should work. Not sure what the OP wants to spawn new PIDs from each time, but this seems to fit the question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I agree that -z would be better generally for modern shells.  I'm dating my self with writing configure script tests that are as backward compatible as possible.  Actually, the true backward compatible test is `"x$FIRST_RUN" = "x"` as some versions of `sh` couldn't even handle empty arguments.

Comment: I think we both probably have far more gray hair than we would like to admit... Chuckling, the old `test "x$somevar" = "x"` check was one of the first I ran across when I started poking around in SuSE 7.0 pro years and years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the script pass an argument to itself indicating that it's already done the initialization (or whatever it is):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" != --init-done ]]; then
    # do initialization/first run stuff here
else
    shift # Remove the --init-done option
fi

...process input...

exec "$BASH_SOURCE" --init-done
```

If the script doesn't take arguments, you can skip the `shift`.